# Dealing with dynamic date differences

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

1. I have a form where I am accepting a duration. This could be a month, a year, 2 months, 20 days etc.
2. Based on this duration, an email is shot to all the kids who have their birthdays x days before this duration.
3. Since, a person can be born in a month with either 28, 29, 30 or 31 days, this makes calculating the date difference a pain.
4. What I've done so far is converted months -> 30 days, years -> 365 days and based on this done my calculations.

What is a more elegant way to deal with such dynamic date differences taking into account different months and leap years?

Comment: There are *set* and *get* methods for just this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding days, months and years is fairly straight forward. When adding months, just check that the date in the new month is the same as the initial month and if it isn't, set the date to 0 (i.e. you've rolled over an extra month so set the date to the end of the previous month). Same for adding years, but it will only happen for February. E.g.

```js
function addMonths(date, months) {
  var d = new Date(+date);
  var startDate = d.getDate();
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + months);
  if (d.getDate() != startDate) d.setDate(0);
  return d;
}

function addYears(date, years) {
  return addMonths(date, years * 12);
}

var d = new Date(2016,4,31);
console.log(d.toLocaleString() + ' plus one month is \n' +
            addMonths(d,1).toLocaleString());

d = new Date(2016,1,29);
console.log(d.toLocaleString() + ' plus one year is \n' + 
            addYears(d, 1).toLocaleString());
```

You can even add these as methods to *Date.prototype* for convenience.

Note that date arithmetic isn't necessarily symmetric.

Comment: It doesn't handle the case of a leap year.
One year from 29th Feb shouldn't be 29th Feb again.

Comment: It completely works for all the other cases, just the one I mentioned.

Comment: Yes it does, see the example. If you add years to 29 Feb 2016 that lands on a leap year you'll get 29 Feb again. A non–leap year will return 28 Feb.

Comment: why adding months * 12 when you can add years?

Comment: Because it saves re–implementing the month roll–over logic. Also, there should be validation that *date* is a Date object and that too can be done once in *addMonths*. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use vanilla js for that -

for months -

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - x);
```

for years -

```
var d = new Date();
d.setYear(d.getYear() - x);
```

for days -

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - x);
```

Comment: thanks, edited the answer - it was anyway more about manipulating the date than creating it in the first place.

Comment: The OP is aware of these methods (I think), but the issue seems to be that adding one month to say 31 Jan goes to 31 Feb, which is adjusted to 2 or 3 March (depending on whether it's a leap year or not). It's those issues that the OP is trying to deal with. It's really only an issue with months and years, since days, hours, etc. are all of equal length (except over daylight saving boundaries…).